# Timezone conversion for datetime field in html emailtemplate in apex using messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate

Tags: apex, email-template, singleemailmessage

I am using html email template in apex to send email to users.The htmlemailbody is rendered by using `messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate` method.I am getting correct emailbody but i am not able to convert the `datetime` fields in the html email template to the receiving user's timezone.I have given `targetobjectid` for the single email as a the corresponding `userid`.
Below is my code:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage dummyMail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateid, contactid, myobjectid);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage  mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(myowid);
mail.setTargetObjectId(userId);                                       
mail.setSubject(dummyMail.getSubject());                                     
mail.setPlainTextBody(dummyMail.getPlainTextBody());
mail.setHTMLBody(dummyMail.getHtmlBody());
```

I just want to convert the `datetime` fields on the html template to match the targetobject (user) timezone

Comment: If it's not working out of the box, you may need to develop a `Visualforce Component` to do the work for you.

Comment: Yeah i thought of it..but hoping whether anything possible with html template